# R: trying to apply broom::tidy on a manipulated df and getting an error

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr, broom, tukey

I'm trying to use `broom::tidy` to organise a nested list created by map (`tukey_res <- map(aov_res, ~tryCatch(TukeyHSD(., ordered = TRUE), error = function(e) NULL))`), using this code: `tukey_res_df <<- bind_rows(map(tukey_res, tidy), .id = "metal")`.

It's working well, but the tukeyHDS results create many variations for the same comparison... so I've tried to narrow the variations by organizing the comparison names inside the nested list, using this:  `tukey_res <<- map(tukey_res, ~ map(.x, function(df) { rownames(df) <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(df), "-"), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "-")) return(df) }))`.

now when I run: `aov_res_df <<- bind_rows(map(aov_res, broom::tidy), .id = "metal")` It raises this error: Error in `map()`:

```
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: 55 Mn ug/g.
Caused by error:
! No tidy method recognized for this list.
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% dcast(metal ~ contrast, value.var = "adj.p.value")
 10. purrr::map(tukey_res, tidy)
 11. purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 16. broom:::tidy.list(.x[[i]], ...)
 17. base::stop("No tidy method recognized for this list.", call. = FALSE)
```

I don't know why Is the same code is working for the original `tukey_res` list (attached), but not the manipulated one (attached).
If someone knows where the problem is or for a better way to manipulate the `tukeyHDS` results to be from the same order, it will save me!

tnx!

the OG `tukey_res`, that is working (the output of `tukey_res <- map(aov_res, ~tryCatch(TukeyHSD(., ordered = TRUE), error = function(e) NULL))`):

```
$`55 Mn ug/g`
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level
    factor levels have been ordered

Fit: aov(formula = formula(englue(".~{{x.var}} * {{z.var}}")), data = df)

$treatment
                        diff       lwr      upr     p adj
reference-pollution 10.98384 -5.531336 27.49901 0.1847596

$year
               diff       lwr       upr     p adj
2019-2020  3.529123 -27.99048  35.04872 0.9974807
2018-2020  9.284692 -43.94380  62.51318 0.9862648
2021-2020 11.367941 -17.44088  40.17677 0.7830216
2022-2020 97.972773  44.74428 151.20126 0.0000777
2018-2019  5.755569 -51.79108  63.30222 0.9983782
2021-2019  7.838818 -28.33152  44.00915 0.9694932
2022-2019 94.443650  36.89700 151.99030 0.0003963
2021-2018  2.083249 -54.02451  58.19101 0.9999680
2022-2018 88.688081  16.91480 160.46136 0.0095330
2022-2021 86.604832  30.49708 142.71259 0.0008715

$`treatment:year`
                                     diff         lwr       upr     p adj
pollution:2018-pollution:2020   0.9900000 -87.9457118  89.92571 1.0000000
reference:2020-pollution:2018   2.6272727 -85.4962238  90.75077 1.0000000
pollution:2019-pollution:2018   5.8898397 -97.4441196 109.22380 1.0000000
reference:2019-pollution:2018   6.5104194 -85.9142835  98.93512 0.9999999
reference:2021-pollution:2018  12.2100000 -78.9219861 103.34199 0.9999803
pollution:2021-pollution:2018  16.5266667 -80.8975244 113.95086 0.9998572
reference:2018-pollution:2018  19.4700000 -99.8497784 138.78978 0.9998965
reference:2022-pollution:2018 103.9150000   0.5810408 207.24896 0.0478261
pollution:2022-pollution:2018          NA          NA        NA        NA
pollution:2019-reference:2020   3.2625669 -61.5945704  68.11970 1.0000000
reference:2019-reference:2020   3.8831466 -41.6236313  49.38992 0.9999996
reference:2021-reference:2020   9.5827273 -33.2375952  52.40305 0.9986785
pollution:2021-reference:2020  13.8993939 -41.0552614  68.85405 0.9966468
reference:2018-reference:2020  16.8427273 -71.2807693 104.96622 0.9996214
reference:2022-reference:2020 101.2877273  36.4305899 166.14486 0.0003282
pollution:2022-reference:2020          NA          NA        NA        NA
reference:2019-pollution:2019   0.6205797 -69.9699532  71.21111 1.0000000
reference:2021-pollution:2019   6.3201603 -62.5691458  75.20947 0.9999993
pollution:2021-pollution:2019  10.6368270 -66.3837588  87.65741 0.9999746
pollution:2021-reference:2019  10.0162473 -51.6002213  71.63272 0.9998997
reference:2018-reference:2019  12.9595806 -79.4651223 105.38428 0.9999711
reference:2022-reference:2019  97.4045806  26.8140478 167.99511 0.0018155
pollution:2022-reference:2019          NA          NA        NA        NA
pollution:2021-reference:2021   4.3166667 -55.3432225  63.97656 0.9999999
pollution:2022-reference:2022          NA          NA        NA        NA


$`63 Cu ug/g`
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level
    factor levels have been ordered

Fit: aov(formula = formula(englue(".~{{x.var}} * {{z.var}}")), data = df)

$treatment
                        diff      lwr      upr    p adj
reference-pollution 9.164472 1.500796 16.82815 0.020654

$year
                diff        lwr      upr     p adj
2019-2021  0.7716086 -16.012818 17.55604 0.9999251
2020-2021  2.3713551 -10.997048 15.73976 0.9853757
2022-2021  6.0568425 -19.979315 32.09300 0.9606963
2018-2021 23.2690787  -2.767079 49.30524 0.0976076
2020-2019  1.5997465 -13.026560 16.22605 0.9977002
2022-2019  5.2852339 -21.418626 31.98909 0.9780672
2018-2019 22.4974701  -4.206389 49.20133 0.1317963
2022-2020  3.6854874 -21.014580 28.38556 0.9923831
2018-2020 20.8977236  -3.802344 45.59779 0.1291267
2018-2022 17.2122362 -16.093328 50.51780 0.5726528

$`treatment:year`
                                   diff        lwr       upr     p adj
pollution:2019-pollution:2018  6.570176 -41.380757  54.52111 0.9999762
pollution:2020-pollution:2018  8.333333 -32.936259  49.60293 0.9994116
pollution:2021-pollution:2018  8.923333 -36.285240  54.13191 0.9995095
reference:2021-pollution:2018 12.013333 -30.275414  54.30208 0.9921935
reference:2019-pollution:2018 14.439813 -28.448805  57.32843 0.9752946
reference:2020-pollution:2018 15.519091 -25.373602  56.41178 0.9482415
reference:2022-pollution:2018 20.095000 -27.855933  68.04593 0.9094557
reference:2018-pollution:2018 65.450000  10.081032 120.81897 0.0108955
pollution:2022-pollution:2018        NA         NA        NA        NA
pollution:2020-pollution:2019  1.763157 -28.843191  32.36951 1.0000000
pollution:2021-pollution:2019  2.353157 -33.387358  38.09367 1.0000000
reference:2021-pollution:2019  5.443157 -26.524131  37.41045 0.9998527
reference:2022-pollution:2020 11.761667 -18.844682  42.36802 0.9442998
reference:2018-pollution:2020 57.116667  15.847075  98.38626 0.0017470
pollution:2022-pollution:2020        NA         NA        NA        NA
reference:2021-pollution:2021  3.090000 -24.594484  30.77448 0.9999959
reference:2019-pollution:2021  5.516480 -23.075932  34.10889 0.9995915
reference:2020-pollution:2021  6.595758 -18.905317  32.09683 0.9960417
reference:2022-pollution:2021 11.171667 -24.568848  46.91218 0.9848680
reference:2018-pollution:2021 56.526667  11.318094 101.73524 0.0059393
pollution:2022-pollution:2021        NA         NA        NA        NA
reference:2019-reference:2021  2.426480 -21.281096  26.13406 0.9999981
reference:2020-reference:2021  3.505758 -16.364519  23.37603 0.9998026
reference:2022-reference:2021  8.081667 -23.885622  40.04896 0.9966581
reference:2018-reference:2021 53.436667  11.147919  95.72541 0.0052703
pollution:2022-reference:2021        NA         NA        NA        NA
reference:2022-reference:2020  4.575909 -25.520298  34.67212 0.9999426
reference:2018-reference:2020 49.930909   9.038216  90.82360 0.0077219
pollution:2022-reference:2020        NA         NA        NA        NA
reference:2018-reference:2022 45.355000  -2.595933  93.30593 0.0759055
pollution:2022-reference:2022        NA         NA        NA        NA
pollution:2022-reference:2018        NA         NA        NA        NA


$`66 Zn ug/g`
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level
    factor levels have been ordered

Fit: aov(formula = formula(englue(".~{{x.var}} * {{z.var}}")), data = df)

$treatment
                        diff       lwr      upr     p adj
reference-pollution 27.84621 -14.94634 70.63875 0.1941469

$year
               diff          lwr       upr     p adj
2019-2020  6.629649  -67.7336434  80.99294 0.9949134
2021-2020 68.157776    0.1899318 136.12562 0.0491572
2022-2020 90.005707  -35.5747597 215.58617 0.2306234
2021-2019 61.528126  -23.8075164 146.86377 0.2260827
2022-2019 83.376058  -52.3921189 219.14423 0.3578833
2022-2021 21.847931 -110.5255037 154.22137 0.9695307

$`treatment:year`
                                    diff        lwr      upr     p adj
reference:2019-pollution:2020  12.773303 -100.19582 125.7424 0.9999465
reference:2020-pollution:2020  19.547778  -71.48534 110.5809 0.9964760
pollution:2019-pollution:2020  44.911556 -113.41803 203.2411 0.9816223
pollution:2021-pollution:2020  51.897778  -83.12615 186.9217 0.9106514
reference:2021-pollution:2020  97.287778   -9.45801 204.0336 0.0947302
reference:2021-reference:2019  84.514475  -38.12710 207.1560 0.3586213
reference:2022-reference:2019 100.514475  -68.93921 269.9682 0.5448080
pollution:2022-reference:2019         NA         NA       NA        NA
pollution:2019-reference:2020  25.363778 -130.32680 181.0544 0.9993924
pollution:2021-reference:2020  32.350000  -99.56951 164.2695 0.9921055
reference:2021-reference:2020  77.740000  -25.05086 180.5309 0.2517188
reference:2022-reference:2020  93.740000  -61.95058 249.4306 0.5264717
pollution:2022-reference:2020         NA         NA       NA        NA
pollution:2021-pollution:2019   6.986222 -177.90291 191.8753 1.0000000
reference:2021-pollution:2019  52.376222 -112.99364 217.7461 0.9663115
reference:2022-pollution:2019  68.376222 -134.15967 270.9121 0.9528951
pollution:2022-pollution:2019         NA         NA       NA        NA
reference:2021-pollution:2021  45.390000  -97.82450 188.6045 0.9661888
reference:2022-reference:2021  16.000000 -149.36986 181.3699 0.9999815
pollution:2022-reference:2021         NA         NA       NA        NA
pollution:2022-reference:2022         NA         NA       NA        NA


$`75 As ug/g`
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level
    factor levels have been ordered

Fit: aov(formula = formula(englue(".~{{x.var}} * {{z.var}}")), data = df)

$treatment
                         diff       lwr      upr     p adj
pollution-reference 0.2750214 -1.785745 2.335788 0.7872845

$year
               diff         lwr      upr     p adj
2021-2019 0.1240732 -3.98544793 4.233594 0.9997982
2022-2019 0.4901915 -6.04801664 7.028400 0.9969535
2020-2021 3.5173586  0.24422111 6.790496 0.0314224
2020-2022 3.1512404 -2.89635671 9.198837 0.5002788

$`treatment:year`
                                    diff       lwr       upr     p adj
reference:2019-pollution:2019 0.09446886 -8.065937  8.254875 1.0000000
pollution:2021-pollution:2019 0.19242501 -8.711308  9.096158 1.0000000
reference:2021-pollution:2019 0.21075835 -7.752983  8.174499 1.0000000
reference:2022-pollution:2019 0.47909168 -9.274459 10.232643 0.9999998
pollution:2020-pollution:2019 3.41353613 -4.211165 11.038238 0.8251927
reference:2020-pollution:2019 4.03272804 -3.464886 11.530342 0.6586600
pollution:2022-pollution:2019         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2021-reference:2019 0.09795616 -7.025030  7.220943 1.0000000
reference:2021-reference:2019 0.11628949 -5.789779  6.022358 1.0000000
reference:2022-reference:2019 0.38462282 -7.775783  8.545029 0.9999999
pollution:2020-reference:2019 3.31906727 -2.121203  8.759338 0.5101307
reference:2020-reference:2019 3.93825919 -1.322415  9.198933 0.2627155
reference:2021-pollution:2021 0.01833333 -6.878469  6.915135 1.0000000
pollution:2020-pollution:2021 3.22111111 -3.281256  9.723478 0.7420254
pollution:2022-reference:2021         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2020-reference:2022 2.93444444 -4.690257 10.559146 0.9101032
reference:2020-reference:2022 3.55363636 -3.943978 11.051251 0.7810426
pollution:2022-reference:2022         NA        NA        NA        NA
reference:2020-pollution:2020 0.61919192 -3.764703  5.003087 0.9997624
pollution:2022-pollution:2020         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2022-reference:2020         NA        NA        NA        NA


$`111 Cd ug/g`
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level
    factor levels have been ordered

Fit: aov(formula = formula(englue(".~{{x.var}} * {{z.var}}")), data = df)

$treatment
                         diff        lwr       upr     p adj
pollution-reference 0.2655667 -0.1493893 0.6805227 0.2014085

$year
                diff         lwr       upr     p adj
2021-2020 0.18526056 -0.47381835 0.8443395 0.8704279
2019-2020 0.68789879 -0.03319629 1.4089939 0.0658465
2022-2021 0.49074447 -0.79287047 1.7743594 0.7289348
2019-2021 0.50263823 -0.32485489 1.3301313 0.3673647
2019-2022 0.01189376 -1.30463973 1.3284272 0.9999946

$`treatment:year`
                                    diff        lwr       upr     p adj
pollution:2020-reference:2020 0.09262626 -0.7901148 0.9753673 0.9999678
reference:2019-reference:2020 0.11099724 -0.9482920 1.1702865 0.9999681
pollution:2021-reference:2020 0.14484848 -1.1343648 1.4240618 0.9999460
reference:2021-reference:2020 0.22151515 -0.7752398 1.2182701 0.9956460
reference:2022-reference:2020 0.59818182 -0.9115377 2.1079013 0.8970993
pollution:2019-reference:2020 2.12333816  0.6136187 3.6330576 0.0016983
pollution:2022-reference:2020         NA         NA        NA        NA
reference:2019-pollution:2020 0.01837098 -1.0770819 1.1138238 1.0000000
pollution:2021-pollution:2020 0.05222222 -1.2570943 1.3615388 1.0000000
reference:2021-pollution:2020 0.12888889 -0.9062167 1.1639945 0.9998976
reference:2022-pollution:2020 0.50555556 -1.0297542 2.0408653 0.9586157
pollution:2019-pollution:2020 2.03071190  0.4954021 3.5660217 0.0035512
pollution:2022-pollution:2020         NA         NA        NA        NA
pollution:2021-reference:2019 0.03385124 -1.4004332 1.4681357 1.0000000
reference:2021-reference:2019 0.11051791 -1.0787279 1.2997637 0.9999859
reference:2022-reference:2019 0.48718457 -1.1559947 2.1303638 0.9764727
pollution:2019-reference:2019 2.01234092  0.3691617 3.6555202 0.0082469
pollution:2022-reference:2019         NA         NA        NA        NA
reference:2021-pollution:2021 0.07666667 -1.3120733 1.4654066 0.9999996
reference:2022-pollution:2021 0.45333333 -1.3395222 2.2461889 0.9905338
pollution:2019-pollution:2021 1.97848967  0.1856341 3.7713452 0.0223918
pollution:2022-pollution:2021         NA         NA        NA        NA
reference:2022-reference:2021 0.37666667 -1.2269121 1.9802454 0.9939017
pollution:2019-reference:2021 1.90182301  0.2982443 3.5054018 0.0114112
pollution:2022-reference:2021         NA         NA        NA        NA
pollution:2019-reference:2022 1.52515634 -0.4388185 3.4891312 0.2242003
pollution:2022-reference:2022         NA         NA        NA        NA
pollution:2022-pollution:2019         NA         NA        NA        NA
```

the manipulated `tukey_res` that raises an error when running `tukey_res_df <<- bind_rows(map(tukey_res, tidy), .id = "metal")` (the output of   `tukey_res <<- map(tukey_res, ~ map(.x, function(df) { rownames(df) <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(df), "-"), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = "-")) return(df) }))`:

```
$`55 Mn ug/g`
$`55 Mn ug/g`$treatment
                        diff       lwr      upr     p adj
pollution-reference 10.98384 -5.531336 27.49901 0.1847596

$`55 Mn ug/g`$year
               diff       lwr       upr        p adj
2019-2020  3.529123 -27.99048  35.04872 0.9974807375
2018-2020  9.284692 -43.94380  62.51318 0.9862648066
2020-2021 11.367941 -17.44088  40.17677 0.7830215735
2020-2022 97.972773  44.74428 151.20126 0.0000776977
2018-2019  5.755569 -51.79108  63.30222 0.9983781688
2019-2021  7.838818 -28.33152  44.00915 0.9694931868
2019-2022 94.443650  36.89700 151.99030 0.0003962957
2018-2021  2.083249 -54.02451  58.19101 0.9999680073
2018-2022 88.688081  16.91480 160.46136 0.0095329888
2021-2022 86.604832  30.49708 142.71259 0.0008715218

$`55 Mn ug/g`$`treatment:year`
                                     diff         lwr       upr        p adj
pollution:2018-pollution:2020   0.9900000 -87.9457118  89.92571 1.0000000000
pollution:2020-reference:2020   3.6172727 -34.3050422  41.53959 0.9999989626
pollution:2019-pollution:2020   6.8798397 -59.0766495  72.83633 0.9999977343
pollution:2020-reference:2019   7.5004194 -39.5599359  54.56077 0.9999149061
pollution:2020-reference:2021  13.2000000 -31.2678559  57.66786 0.9893736601
pollution:2020-pollution:2021  17.5166667 -38.7312163  73.76455 0.9852426525
pollution:2020-reference:2018  20.4600000 -68.4757118 109.39571 0.9983643008
pollution:2020-reference:2022 104.9050000  38.9485108 170.86149 0.0002496682
pollution:2020-pollution:2022          NA          NA        NA           NA
pollution:2018-reference:2020   2.6272727 -85.4962238  90.75077 1.0000000000
pollution:2018-pollution:2019   5.8898397 -97.4441196 109.22380 0.9999999891
pollution:2018-reference:2019   6.5104194 -85.9142835  98.93512 0.9999999284
pollution:2018-reference:2021  12.2100000 -78.9219861 103.34199 0.9999803480
pollution:2018-pollution:2021  16.5266667 -80.8975244 113.95086 0.9998571623
pollution:2018-reference:2018  19.4700000 -99.8497784 138.78978 0.9998964724
pollution:2018-reference:2022 103.9150000   0.5810408 207.24896 0.0478260735
pollution:2018-pollution:2022          NA          NA        NA           NA
pollution:2019-reference:2020   3.2625669 -61.5945704  68.11970 0.9999999964
reference:2019-reference:2020   3.8831466 -41.6236313  49.38992 0.9999996101
reference:2020-reference:2021   9.5827273 -33.2375952  52.40305 0.9986785080
pollution:2021-reference:2020  13.8993939 -41.0552614  68.85405 0.9966468062
reference:2018-reference:2020  16.8427273 -71.2807693 104.96622 0.9996214268
reference:2020-reference:2022 101.2877273  36.4305899 166.14486 0.0003282315
pollution:2022-reference:2020          NA          NA        NA           NA
pollution:2019-reference:2019   0.6205797 -69.9699532  71.21111 1.0000000000
pollution:2019-reference:2021   6.3201603 -62.5691458  75.20947 0.9999992627
pollution:2019-pollution:2021  10.6368270 -66.3837588  87.65741 0.9999745610
pollution:2019-reference:2018  13.5801603 -89.7537989 116.91412 0.9999833346
pollution:2019-reference:2022  98.0251603  13.6533359 182.39698 0.0130027871
pollution:2019-pollution:2022          NA          NA        NA           NA
reference:2019-reference:2021   5.6995806 -45.3900962  56.78926 0.9999959361
pollution:2021-reference:2019  10.0162473 -51.6002213  71.63272 0.9998996836
reference:2018-reference:2019  12.9595806 -79.4651223 105.38428 0.9999710566
reference:2021-reference:2022  91.7050000  22.8156938 160.59431 0.0028464572
pollution:2022-reference:2021          NA          NA        NA           NA
pollution:2021-reference:2018   2.9433333 -94.4808577 100.36752 1.0000000000
pollution:2021-reference:2022  87.3883333  10.3677476 164.40892 0.0164495943
pollution:2021-pollution:2022          NA          NA        NA           NA
reference:2018-reference:2022  84.4450000 -18.8889592 187.77896 0.1870465506
pollution:2022-reference:2018          NA          NA        NA           NA
pollution:2022-reference:2022          NA          NA        NA           NA


$`63 Cu ug/g`
$`63 Cu ug/g`$treatment
                        diff      lwr      upr      p adj
pollution-reference 9.164472 1.500796 16.82815 0.02065404

$`63 Cu ug/g`$year
                diff        lwr      upr      p adj
2019-2021  0.7716086 -16.012818 17.55604 0.99992506
2020-2021  2.3713551 -10.997048 15.73976 0.98537566
2021-2022  6.0568425 -19.979315 32.09300 0.96069626
2018-2021 23.2690787  -2.767079 49.30524 0.09760756
2019-2020  1.5997465 -13.026560 16.22605 0.99770025
2019-2022  5.2852339 -21.418626 31.98909 0.97806720
2018-2019 22.4974701  -4.206389 49.20133 0.13179626
2020-2022  3.6854874 -21.014580 28.38556 0.99238306
2018-2020 20.8977236  -3.802344 45.59779 0.12912670
2018-2022 17.2122362 -16.093328 50.51780 0.57265282

$`63 Cu ug/g`$`treatment:year`
                                   diff        lwr       upr       p adj
pollution:2018-pollution:2019  6.570176 -41.380757  54.52111 0.999976212
pollution:2018-pollution:2022        NA         NA        NA          NA
pollution:2019-pollution:2020  1.763157 -28.843191  32.36951 0.999999988
pollution:2019-reference:2022 13.524824 -25.626949  52.67660 0.970885469
pollution:2019-reference:2018 58.879824  10.928891 106.83076 0.007261540
pollution:2019-pollution:2022        NA         NA        NA          NA
pollution:2020-pollution:2021  0.590000 -25.511182  26.69118 1.000000000
pollution:2020-reference:2021  3.680000 -16.954796  24.31480 0.999784435
pollution:2020-reference:2019  6.106480 -15.731336  27.94430 0.993023265
pollution:2020-reference:2020  7.185758 -10.411656  24.78317 0.921385838
pollution:2020-reference:2022 11.761667 -18.844682  42.36802 0.944299839
pollution:2020-reference:2018 57.116667  15.847075  98.38626 0.001747035
pollution:2020-pollution:2022        NA         NA        NA          NA
pollution:2021-reference:2021  3.090000 -24.594484  30.77448 0.999995919
pollution:2021-reference:2019  5.516480 -23.075932  34.10889 0.999591544
pollution:2021-reference:2020  6.595758 -18.905317  32.09683 0.996041733
pollution:2021-reference:2022 11.171667 -24.568848  46.91218 0.984868036
pollution:2021-reference:2018 56.526667  11.318094 101.73524 0.005939311
pollution:2021-pollution:2022        NA         NA        NA          NA
reference:2019-reference:2021  2.426480 -21.281096  26.13406 0.999998079
reference:2020-reference:2021  3.505758 -16.364519  23.37603 0.999802620
reference:2021-reference:2022  8.081667 -23.885622  40.04896 0.996658073
reference:2018-reference:2021 53.436667  11.147919  95.72541 0.005270311
pollution:2022-reference:2021        NA         NA        NA          NA
reference:2019-reference:2020  1.079278 -20.037618  22.19617 0.999999996
reference:2019-reference:2022  5.655187 -27.101536  38.41191 0.999834891
reference:2018-reference:2019 51.010187   8.121569  93.89880 0.010219273
pollution:2022-reference:2019        NA         NA        NA          NA
reference:2020-reference:2022  4.575909 -25.520298  34.67212 0.999942650
reference:2018-reference:2020 49.930909   9.038216  90.82360 0.007721903
pollution:2022-reference:2020        NA         NA        NA          NA
reference:2018-reference:2022 45.355000  -2.595933  93.30593 0.075905491
pollution:2022-reference:2022        NA         NA        NA          NA
pollution:2022-reference:2018        NA         NA        NA          NA


$`66 Zn ug/g`
$`66 Zn ug/g`$treatment
                        diff       lwr      upr     p adj
pollution-reference 27.84621 -14.94634 70.63875 0.1941469

$`66 Zn ug/g`$year
               diff          lwr       upr     p adj
2019-2020  6.629649  -67.7336434  80.99294 0.9949134
2020-2021 68.157776    0.1899318 136.12562 0.0491572
2020-2022 90.005707  -35.5747597 215.58617 0.2306234
2019-2021 61.528126  -23.8075164 146.86377 0.2260827
2019-2022 83.376058  -52.3921189 219.14423 0.3578833
2021-2022 21.847931 -110.5255037 154.22137 0.9695307

$`66 Zn ug/g`$`treatment:year`
                                    diff        lwr      upr      p adj
pollution:2020-reference:2019  12.773303 -100.19582 125.7424 0.99994653
pollution:2020-reference:2020  19.547778  -71.48534 110.5809 0.99647595
pollution:2019-pollution:2020  44.911556 -113.41803 203.2411 0.98162232
pollution:2020-pollution:2021  51.897778  -83.12615 186.9217 0.91065143
pollution:2020-reference:2021  97.287778   -9.45801 204.0336 0.09473016
pollution:2020-reference:2022 113.287778  -45.04181 271.6174 0.31381105
pollution:2020-pollution:2022         NA         NA       NA         NA
reference:2019-reference:2020   6.774475 -102.46526 116.0142 0.99999913
pollution:2019-reference:2019  32.138253 -137.31543 201.5919 0.99838275
pollution:2021-reference:2019  39.124475 -108.78683 187.0358 0.98767867
reference:2019-reference:2021  84.514475  -38.12710 207.1560 0.35862129
reference:2019-reference:2022 100.514475  -68.93921 269.9682 0.54480796
pollution:2022-reference:2019         NA         NA       NA         NA
pollution:2019-reference:2020  25.363778 -130.32680 181.0544 0.99939243
pollution:2021-reference:2020  32.350000  -99.56951 164.2695 0.99210549
reference:2020-reference:2021  77.740000  -25.05086 180.5309 0.25171876
reference:2020-reference:2022  93.740000  -61.95058 249.4306 0.52647168
pollution:2022-reference:2020         NA         NA       NA         NA
pollution:2019-pollution:2021   6.986222 -177.90291 191.8753 0.99999997
pollution:2019-reference:2021  52.376222 -112.99364 217.7461 0.96631154
pollution:2019-reference:2022  68.376222 -134.15967 270.9121 0.95289505
pollution:2019-pollution:2022         NA         NA       NA         NA
pollution:2021-reference:2021  45.390000  -97.82450 188.6045 0.96618885
pollution:2021-reference:2022  61.390000 -123.49913 246.2791 0.95677949
pollution:2021-pollution:2022         NA         NA       NA         NA
reference:2021-reference:2022  16.000000 -149.36986 181.3699 0.99998146
pollution:2022-reference:2021         NA         NA       NA         NA
pollution:2022-reference:2022         NA         NA       NA         NA


$`75 As ug/g`
$`75 As ug/g`$treatment
                         diff       lwr      upr     p adj
pollution-reference 0.2750214 -1.785745 2.335788 0.7872845

$`75 As ug/g`$year
               diff         lwr      upr      p adj
2019-2021 0.1240732 -3.98544793 4.233594 0.99979820
2019-2022 0.4901915 -6.04801664 7.028400 0.99695352
2019-2020 3.6414318  0.06030777 7.222556 0.04510948
2021-2022 0.3661183 -6.00860879 6.740845 0.99862088
2020-2021 3.5173586  0.24422111 6.790496 0.03142245
2020-2022 3.1512404 -2.89635671 9.198837 0.50027878

$`75 As ug/g`$`treatment:year`
                                    diff       lwr       upr     p adj
pollution:2019-reference:2019 0.09446886 -8.065937  8.254875 1.0000000
pollution:2019-pollution:2021 0.19242501 -8.711308  9.096158 1.0000000
pollution:2019-reference:2021 0.21075835 -7.752983  8.174499 1.0000000
pollution:2019-reference:2022 0.47909168 -9.274459 10.232643 0.9999998
pollution:2019-pollution:2020 3.41353613 -4.211165 11.038238 0.8251927
pollution:2019-reference:2020 4.03272804 -3.464886 11.530342 0.6586600
pollution:2019-pollution:2022         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2021-reference:2019 0.09795616 -7.025030  7.220943 1.0000000
reference:2019-reference:2021 0.11628949 -5.789779  6.022358 1.0000000
reference:2019-reference:2022 0.38462282 -7.775783  8.545029 0.9999999
pollution:2020-reference:2019 3.31906727 -2.121203  8.759338 0.5101307
reference:2019-reference:2020 3.93825919 -1.322415  9.198933 0.2627155
pollution:2022-reference:2019         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2021-reference:2021 0.01833333 -6.878469  6.915135 1.0000000
pollution:2021-reference:2022 0.28666667 -8.617066  9.190400 1.0000000
pollution:2022-reference:2021         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2020-reference:2022 2.93444444 -4.690257 10.559146 0.9101032
reference:2020-reference:2022 3.55363636 -3.943978 11.051251 0.7810426
pollution:2022-reference:2022         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2020-reference:2020 0.61919192 -3.764703  5.003087 0.9997624
pollution:2020-pollution:2022         NA        NA        NA        NA
pollution:2022-reference:2020         NA        NA        NA        NA


$`111 Cd ug/g`
$`111 Cd ug/g`$treatment
                         diff        lwr       upr     p adj
pollution-reference 0.2655667 -0.1493893 0.6805227 0.2014085

$`111 Cd ug/g`$year
                diff         lwr       upr      p adj
2020-2021 0.18526056 -0.47381835 0.8443395 0.87042787
2020-2022 0.67600503 -0.54173902 1.8937491 0.44582461
2019-2020 0.68789879 -0.03319629 1.4089939 0.06584652
2021-2022 0.49074447 -0.79287047 1.7743594 0.72893482
2019-2021 0.50263823 -0.32485489 1.3301313 0.36736474
2019-2022 0.01189376 -1.30463973 1.3284272 0.99999458

$`111 Cd ug/g`$`treatment:year`
                                    diff        lwr       upr       p adj
pollution:2020-reference:2020 0.09262626 -0.7901148 0.9753673 0.999967778
reference:2019-reference:2020 0.11099724 -0.9482920 1.1702865 0.999968081
pollution:2021-reference:2020 0.14484848 -1.1343648 1.4240618 0.999946005
reference:2020-reference:2021 0.22151515 -0.7752398 1.2182701 0.995645974
reference:2020-reference:2022 0.59818182 -0.9115377 2.1079013 0.897099298
pollution:2019-reference:2020 2.12333816  0.6136187 3.6330576 0.001698314
pollution:2022-reference:2020         NA         NA        NA          NA
pollution:2020-reference:2019 0.01837098 -1.0770819 1.1138238 1.000000000
pollution:2020-pollution:2021 0.05222222 -1.2570943 1.3615388 0.999999960
pollution:2020-reference:2021 0.12888889 -0.9062167 1.1639945 0.999897574
pollution:2020-reference:2022 0.50555556 -1.0297542 2.0408653 0.958615656
pollution:2019-pollution:2020 2.03071190  0.4954021 3.5660217 0.003551222
pollution:2020-pollution:2022         NA         NA        NA          NA
pollution:2021-reference:2019 0.03385124 -1.4004332 1.4681357 0.999999999
reference:2019-reference:2021 0.11051791 -1.0787279 1.2997637 0.999985922
reference:2019-reference:2022 0.48718457 -1.1559947 2.1303638 0.976472724
reference:2021-reference:2022 0.37666667 -1.2269121 1.9802454 0.993901688
```